# Multiple AngularJS services auth token in a centralized place/ component

Tags: angularjs, authentication, service, token, centralized

For multiple AngularJS services that makes it's own Web API calls, we need to store the authentication token in a centralized place and it shouldn't be repeated. Where should we save the authentication token? I guess we need to write a authentication AngularJS service that would be responsible for log-in/log-out and it stores the generated token in client local storage so this token can be sent with each request to access secure resources on the back-end API. Kindly answer me if my understanding in correct.

Comment: XSRF is an attack technique by which the attacker can trick an authenticated user into unknowingly executing actions on your website.. Read this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http  .. XSRF : help you..

Comment: Thanks Manikandan. It's a configuration question like where in one place I'll handle authentication that needs to be passed with header

Comment: Ok . Welcome @Revathi....